# python interpreter on non-pydev projects?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

we have successfully added pydev plugin on our eclipse. as a result in pydev projects it detects errors and so on.

but the question is that is there any way that we use pydev abilities (e.g. error detection) in non-pydev projects?(e.g. a java project).

actually we are developing an eclipse plugin that contains some .py files and we want it to interpret them as a side feature

Answer (score 0):

PyDev should be working fine. In project properties, you can set interpreter, PYTHONPATH and other PyDev related settings.

To manually trigger code analysis, right-click on project, file or folder and select `PyDev`->`Code analysis`

Comment: Do you have Python installed? I created Java project with python files and pydev is working properly! (I'm using PyDev 2.6 with Eclipse 4.2)

Comment: I just installed pydev using help->install new software.
It works but for example can not distinguish errors that can be distinguished in pydev project, just auto complete works!

Comment: What kind of errors? Could you try to manually trigger code analysis?

Comment: imports and every thing, I try to write random letters between code and it cat diagnose just some of them!
yes, I try that.

Comment: make sure you have your source folder added to the project's PYTHONPATH